# RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-server

I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to add the *Microsoft.SharePoint.dll* to GAC. For that one I have used below code

Code :

```
 `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> Regasm.exe "C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"`
```

When I press entry key, then I am getting the below error:-

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Native, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependenceies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please can any one help to get out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use Gacutil instead of Regasm. So,

```
gacutil /i Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
```

Difference between regasm and gacutil:

**Regasm**: The Assembly Registration tool reads the metadata within an assembly and adds the necessary entries to the registry, which allows COM clients to create .NET Framework classes transparently. Once a class is registered, any COM client can use it as though the class were a COM class. The class is registered only once, when the assembly is installed. Instances of classes within the assembly cannot be created from COM until they are actually registered. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Gacutil**: The Global Assembly Cache tool allows you to view and manipulate the contents of the global assembly cache and download cache. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[More details](http://jussionsharepoint.com/index.php/2012/02/08/using-global-assembly-cache-tool-gacutil-exe-effectively/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will help me lot. But can you tell me what is different between gacutil and regams.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it clarifies the difference.

Comment: Note, using Gacutil requires a strong name for the assembly